# javascript not working to append to the end of the docmap div tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering why my javascript isn't working to append to the end of the docmap div tag?
At least I try it in chrome and I don't see it say: "Some new content!" in the docmap div tag.

```
<html>
<header>
<style>
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: 200px; 
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    //alert("hey!");
    var docmap = $("#docmap");
    docmap.append('<br>Some new content!');
</script>
</header>

<body>

<div id="docmap">
<ul>
<li> hello
<li> hi
<li> howdy
</ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
<h1>header1</h1>
<h2>header2 a</h2>
<h2>header2 b</h2>
<h1>header1 a</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have your code in the header, the DOM doesn't even exist yet.  Either use JQuery DOM ready, or place your script before the body close tag.

Comment: shouldn't the console report an error if that's the case?

Comment: No, jquery works on collections, if the collection is empty, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: @pico there is no error in this case - you try to find an element using `$("#docmap")` and since it doesn't exist, you get an empty collection. When you try to do anything with it, it's just a no-op.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $(document).ready necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/is-document-ready-necessary)

Comment: is there a way to wait for the doc to be created and keep the script in the header?

Comment: @pico yes, using `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @pico why would you want to keep the script in `head`?

Answer (score 1):

In the `<html>` tag, you should use `<head>`. `<header>` is a tag for another purpose. Also you must move your script in the bottom on the body after the declaration of the tag you are looking to call with JQuery.

[Try it Online!](https://jsbin.com/doxumecuxe/1/edit?html,output) or directly here:

```js
    //alert("hey!");
var docmap = $("#docmap");
docmap.append('<br>Some new content!');
```

```css
#docmap {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; 
}
#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: 200px; 
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="docmap">
<ul>
<li> hello
<li> hi
<li> howdy
</ul>
</div>
```

There is a Q&A about `<head>` vs `<header>`: [<header> vs. <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434950/header-vs-head)

If you are wondering where to put the `<script>` tag, well SO has your back:

- [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)
- [Is it wrong to place the <script> tag after the </body> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag)
- [Advantages of script tag before closing body tag when using events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441730/advantages-of-script-tag-before-closing-body-tag-when-using-events)
- [Should I place <script> before or after the </html> closing tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340166/should-i-place-script-before-or-after-the-html-closing-tag)
- [Calling Javascript function before body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602462/calling-javascript-function-before-body-tag)
- [where to place my script tag before closing of</body> or after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464786/where-to-place-my-script-tag-before-closing-of-body-or-after-it)